# How to read a group of datasets as files in a folder?

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy, fits

I am working with sunpy's class sunpy.map.Map(), which operates '.fits' files. Usually, it collects those files directly through directories:

```
import sunpy.map

map_seq = sunpy.map.Map('C:/Usr/sunpy/data')
```

However, I am looking for a way of using this .Map() function with already opened '.fits' files on the code. I have a list of 3 '.fits' files and have tried:

```
map_seq = sunpy.map.Map(['fits1.fits','fits2.fits','fits3.fits'])
```

But it returns: *IndexError: pop index out of range*. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: According to the docs the Map factory takes variable positional arguments so just try your files as individual arguments without the `[]`